# Email Message RelatedToId spelling mistake error

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm building a record triggered flow on the Email Object where I have to write a formula for my entry condition. I want to use the RelatedToId field which I'm selecting from the "Insert a Resource" tool but when validating the formula I keep getting an error message about the spelling not being correct. Why is this happening?

[image]